# 1.4 update resetting the ~/.gazebo/models folder

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's possible I've just forgotten where I put the model I was working with a couple weeks ago, but I think it was in the ~/.gazebo/models/ folder.

1. Would 1.4 have reset the contents of this folder?
2. If so, is there a way of recovering it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1312/1.4-update-resetting-the-%7E/.gazebo/models-folder/) by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 175 on 2013-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's slightly dangerous to put models that you're working on in the `~/.gazebo/models` folder. The danger only comes into play if you happen to give the model that same name as a model currently in the model database, and you download that model from the database. Otherwise, you should be safe.

If the model is not in your `.gazebo/models` folder, then it's probably someplace else on your computer.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-02-09**:
Ah yes. Found it.  Silly question.  Thanks for the info regarding the ~/.gazebo/models folder.